# Can one have multiple queries in streaming analytics job?

Tags: t-sql, azure, analytics, cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics

As the title says, can you have more than one query in an Azure Streaming Analytics job? If so, how should that be structured?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

yes, you can have multiple queries in stream analytics job.
You would do something like below

```
select * into type1Output from inputSource where type = 1
select * into type2Output from inputSource where type = 2
```

The job has two outputs defined, called type1Output and type2Output. Each query writes to a different output.

Comment: How about writing to the same output? For example, there is a web application in which user can create alerts in realtime and those alerts should be processed by same output.